# compare two array values (if contains) and get difference

Tags: javascript

How to compare two array values and get the difference.

```
const list1 = ['1xx', '2bbb', '3ggg', '4eee'];
const list2 = ['1xx33', '2333', '3gfffgg', '4eeeooo'];
```

I'd like to check if list2 values contains list1s

so `1xx33 contains 1xx` and  `4eeeooo contains 4eee` then the result I respect to see is `['2bbb', '3ggg']`;

```
const output = list1.filter( function(n) { return !this.has(n) }, new Set(list2) );
```

Above snippet only gives matches but not contains

Comment: Step one, determine the Regex you need.  You can create this dynamically.  Step 2, walk list1 and scan list2.  Step 3 remove items, step 4, variable assignment or print.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every entry in the first list, you must verify if there is no matching substring in any of the values in the second list.

`const output = list1.filter(s => list2.every(b => (b.indexOf(s)===-1)));`

This snippet creates a new list by filtering the first list, removing every entry that has at least one matching substring when compared to the other list.

If you're not familiar with [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) (`=>`), here's the alternative:

`const output = list1.filter(function(s) { return list2.every(function(b) { return (b.indexOf(s)===-1) })});`

Comment: Good one.Nice Job!